# Telegram send unsaved contact

Tags: android, contacts, telegram, telegram-bot, samsung-galaxy

**Short**: Is there any way to send phone number of unsaved contacts in telegram?

**Long**: I need to send unsaved contact to telegram bot like 20 times a day.
I know, than I can open phone app > go to "recent" tab > click on unsaved phone number > copy it > switch back to telegram > paste it. Is there any way to send it automatically or simplify this process?

I am not asking you about fully working program. Just tell if it is possible or give me ideas.

So far, I found that it is possible to send my phone number to telegram bot via [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#locations-and-numbers). But can't find a way to send unsaved contact.

Also, telegram has built-in feature to send contacts, but it works only with telegram contacts, not with unsaved phone numbers.

So far, I came up with using auto clicker.

**This may help you**:
  My phone is Android device. I am using default Samsung phone app. And I have full control over that telegram bot.

**Links**:

[Telegram API](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.keyboardbutton.html#KeyboardButton.request_contact)

[Telegram API #2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendcontact)

[Telegram API #3](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton)

[Example of unsaved phone number in contacts app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwozH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send contacts using a code like below when you program in Telegram Bot API:

```
await Bot.SendContactAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, Phone_Number, "First_Name", "Last_Name");
```

Here inside your own app (which could be telegram android bot) you can access your phone's call log and replace the Phone Number (which is a string) with phone numbers that your bot extracts locally.

> By the way, Last Name is optional in the code that I mentioned.